# How to read item from DynamoDB using client side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm struggling to understand what needs to be done to press a button in a browser window that triggers a query to my DynamoDB and returns the queried data. I'm one of those people used to much simpler dbs like parse and firebase. I'm trying to level up to aws and the struggle is very real.

Is it necessary to configure an API to handle this round trip or am I just missing something simple?

When running the code below I get a `Missing region in config` error.

```
    var config = new AWS.Config({
        accessKeyId: '####################',
        secretAccessKey: '#####################',
        'region': 'us-east-1'
    });

    var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    var params = {
        AttributesToGet: [
          "city"
        ],
        TableName : 'Venues',
        Key : { 
          "zip" : {
            "N" : "19382"
          }
        }
      }

      db.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err); // an error occurred
          } 
        else {
          console.log(data); // successful response
          res.send(data);
          }
        return next();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Instead of this:

```
var config = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId: '####################',
    secretAccessKey: '#####################',
    'region': 'us-east-1'
});
```

It should be:

```
    AWS.config.accessKeyId = '########################';
    AWS.config.secretAccessKey = '##################';
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```